# Scala implicitly extend an interface

Tags: scala, typeclass

How can I make arbitrary type `T` to conform to `trait Run` without having inherit the trait? Type class works at method level but class is expecting type `Run` and I cannot change method signature of `run()` as it is overriding an interface.

```
trait Run[T] {
  def run(): Unit
}

class SomeClass(runner: Run[_]) extends Runnable {
  @override def run() {
    runner.run()
  }
}
```

Current solution:

```
class SomeRunnable(someRunnable: SomeType) {     
  @override def run(){
    someRunabble.someMethod()   
  }  
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: What for does the `trait Run[T]` need its type parameter `T` in the first place? Why does `SomeRunnable` not extend `Run[SomeType]`?